# Data starting with same words in sunspot rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

My controller is

```
  @search = Sunspot.search(User) do
    fulltext params[:search]
  end
  @search_products = @search.results
```

I want it also match those name which start with search params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a new type  in your solr schema file (solr/conf/schame.xml). Add this to your schema.xml under **types** tag :

```
<fieldType class="solr.TextField" name="text_pre" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="10" />
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Here minGramSize is the minimum number of characters and maxGramSize is the maximum number of characters to start with that can be searched.
For example, minGramSize=8 would mean that a word like **Kapil Kumar Yadav** can be searched with all these substring => "K", "Ka", "Kap", "Kapi", "Kapil", "Kapil ", "Kapil K", "Kapil Ku", but will not be searched with search params having length geater then 8 characters, so its suggested to keep a value for maxGramSize that fits all your fields that have been indexed.  
Now create a new dynamic field definition in same solr schama file, Add this to your schema.xml under **fields** tag:

```
<dynamicField name="*_textp" stored="false" type="text_pre" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
```

Finally onfigure all text fields in **User** class to index into your newly created dynamic field using **as** option like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    searchable do
      text :name, as: :name_textp
      text :address, as: :address_textp
      # etc.
    end
end
```

I found this here [Matching substrings in fulltext search](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Matching-substrings-in-fulltext-search)